# How to make return char function in c programming?

Tags: c

I'm Trying to do some simple c programming that will return the char value. The program is running with no error but, the output of the expected string does not appear. What I expected it will return the `Halloworld` when i run it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char screen(char c[]);

int main(){

    char b[] = "Hallo";
    //screen(b);
    printf("%s",screen(b));
}

char screen(char c[]){

    strcat(c, "world");
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Does that program even compile? You appear to be attempting an implicit conversion from `char[]` to `char` and I would expect a compile-time error from that.

Comment: More importantly: `b` is a constant object without enough space for any more data to be appended to it, which means this program is *undefined behavior* and anything could happen, including nothing at all.

Comment: yes, the program are compiled but it give the warning like this in the 'screen' function warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Comment: That's a very important warning! (And you probably should be compiling with `-Wall -Werror` or whatever the equivalent in your compiler would be: don't just ignore a compiler warning like that.) If you don't understand that warning, then that's a good question in itself (but I'm pretty sure it's been asked and answered thoroughly already here somewhere).

Comment: @WanAfifiWanZain does the reply I put solve your question?  Feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: `char` means a single character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration of [`strcat()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm) returns a pointer to char (`char *`).  So your function `screen()` must also.

Another thing is, you can't do this `char b[] = "Hallo";`, because then the character array `b` is only large enough to handle `Hallo`.  You'll need it larger than `Hallo`, and the rest will be filled with `0x00`, or `NUL`.  Like so:

`48 61 6C 6C 6F 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

And then after you `strcat()` the characters `world` onto the end:

`48 61 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6C 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

The first left over `0x00` will act as a null terminator when passed to `printf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* screen(char c[])
{
    strcat(c, "world");
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    char b[20] = "Hallo ";
    screen(b);
    printf("%s",b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: may i know why we must put pointer on the function? while 'int function' or 'float function' will do just fine without using pointer on the function.

Comment: @Wan: Because an `int` is just an `int` but a string (array of char) is more than just a `char`. The convention in C is to use a pointer to the first char of the string to represent a string.